# Click action getting called multiple times for dynamically generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

On a ajax call I am generating a div and also creating a click action associated with this div. I assign the div a unique Id based on key value coming from data. Problem doing this

```
var $orderData = $('<div><table width="100%"><tr><td nowrap width="15%">'+valX1
                + '</td><td width="10%" class="imgClass" ><img src=' 
                + imgPath + ' id="img_'+serId+'" /></td> 
                + <td nowrap width="25%">' + customerName 
                + '</td><td nowrap width="25%">' + orderPendingCount 
                + '</td><td nowrap width="25%">' 
                + plant+'</td></tr>' + '<tr><td nowrap width="15%">' + modelName 
                + '</td><td></td><td nowrap width="25%">' 
                + totalNo + '</td><td nowrap width="25%">' 
                + deliveredTotal+'</td><td nowrap width="25%">'
                + salesPersonName + '</td></tr></table></div>'  );


$('body').on('click', '#img_'+serId, function(){
    $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
    alert(serId);
    return false;
});
```

Click action gets called correctly.

Issue occurs when same serId comes with the ajax call.
I am assuming the click action gets created again for the div. This causes repeated click action call.

Is there a way I can clear the div action script and div before I create it again

Comment: Check to see if the handler already exists (or don't, depending on your impementation), and then call `$(body).off('click')` to decouple the existing event handler before assigning the new one

Comment: use a class instead of an id

Comment: You call the click action at your ajax function? That's the problem. Each time your ajax runs, it will create a click function for your elements.

Comment: Could you provide code where you add $orderData to page?

Comment: @ klauskpm I already know that. 

There is no escape for me there. The ajax call is actually jtable load. and I am creating custom row with the data received in jtable.

@Jonathan Brooks, will try working with your suggestion. This might do it. My thought process was the same except I did not know the actual call (off) to help myself

Answer (score 0):

you should just use a class what ever has that class will automatically get that event after:

```
$('body').on('click', '.divImgClass', function(){
    $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
    alert(serId);
    return false;
});
```

Then you won't have to reset the event in the first place it will just be there on that class

Answer (score 0):

insert the script before your regenerate the div and try

```
if($('#divid').length != 0) {
  $('#divid').remove();
}
```